# Convergence in $L^p$ of $X_nY_n$ given $X_n$ and $Y_n$ converge

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

My definition for convergence in $L^p$ is the following;

A sequence $x_n \to x$ in $L^p$ to a random variable $x$ if $|x|^p$ is integrable and $E[|x_n -x|^p] \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

My question is, if $x_n \to x$ in $L^p$ as $n \to \infty$ and $y_n \to y$ in $L^p$ as $n \to \infty$ then does $x_ny_n \to xy$ in $L^p$ as $n \to \infty$. Justify the answer by either providing a counter example or a proof.

I "think" its not true but i can't think of a counter example, could somebody please answer this.

Comment: Hint: set up the inequality, but try to add and subtract $XY_n$.

Comment: In general, the product of two functions in $L^p$ does not even have to be in $L^p$. So you don't even get to ask the question about convergence, in the general case. Now, if you were asking about $x_n \to x$ in $L^p$ and $y_n \to y$ in $L^q$ (with $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$) and the convergence of $x_ny_n$ in $L^1$, that would be a standard result.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand, could you provide a bit more information

Comment: Could you tell me please if it statement is true or false so I am not wasting anymore time trying to show something or find an example when its impossible

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen

Answer (score 0):

Let the underlying probability space be the interval $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure as the probability measure.

Define $$f_a(t)=t^a$$ for $t\in(0,1]$. (It is undefined at $t=0$, which is no problem since $\{0\}$ has probability zero.) Now note the following:

- $f_a\in L^p$ if and only if $ap>-1$. If so, $$E[f_a^p]=\frac1{ap+1}.$$
- $f_af_b=f_{a+b}$.

First, note that this shows that the product of two $L^p$ variables do not need to belong to $L^p$: Just pick $a$ and $b$ so that $ap>-1$ and $bp>-1$, but $ap+bp \le -1$.

This should already give a strong hint that multiplication is not continuous even where it is defined. We work it out as follows:

Let $$a_n=\frac1p\Bigl(-\frac12+\frac1n\Bigr),\quad b_n=\frac1{n^{1/(2p)}},$$
and define $$x_n=b_nf_{a_n}.$$
You will find that $E[x_n^p]\to0$, i.e., $x_n\to0$ in $L^p$.

On the other hand, $x_n^2=b_n^2f_{2a_n}$, and so
$$ E[(x_n^2)p]=\frac{b_n^p}{2a_np+1}=\frac12,$$
and so $x_n^2\in L^p$, but $x_n^2$ does not converge to zero in $L^p$.

Comment: If I made any errors in my calculations, I am pretty confident they are easy to fix. The *principle* ought to be right.